# I stained my lab workstation with Coomassie blue. How do I clean it?

Tags: cleaning

I stained my work station with Coomassie blue solution during my SDS-PAGE protocol. I have been cleaning but the solution seems to can't be removed. What should I use to remove all these stains?

Comment: What is the surface of the work-station made of? How long have the stains been there?  What are you using to clean the stains?

Comment: What is a SDS-PAGE protocol ?

Comment: Coomassie Blue is colorless at pH 1 - 3. So by adding a $\ce{HCl}$ solution diluted to about 0.01 M, it should make the blue dye colorless.

Comment: The color will come back once HCl evaporates. A very dilute solution of bleach (used as per manufacturer's and lab instructions) should remove dye stains.

Comment: Use organic solvents, like ethanol, DMSO, etc.

Comment: Why bother at least you will know its yours :)